# Converting string of bytes to Hex in python

Tags: python

Given this file (utf8):

```
00000000  30 31 3a 32 35 20 e2 87  92 20 31 32 2f 32 34 2f  |01:25 ... 12/24/|
00000010  32 30 31 39 20 e2 87 89  30 31 3a 33 31 20 44 49  |2019 ...01:31 DI|
00000020  53 4b 20 46 20 e2 99 a3  20 0d 0a                 |SK F ... ..|
```

My intent is to take a file or string of bytes, and convert it to the hex representation.
I have created the following code:

```
def c2h(data):
    def c2h(c):
        hb = hex(ord(c)).replace('0x','')
        return hb if len(hb) == 2 else ''.join('0'+hb)
    strbuf = []
    i = 0
    for c in data:
        if ord(c) > 255:
        raise ValueError("ord value of char @ position:{:2d} is > 255".format(i))
        strbuf.append(c2h(c))
        i += 1
    return ''.join(strbuf)
```

I then took the above code and ran it in a Mac, Windows and Linux. Here are the results.

Mac: Python 2.7.16

```
>>> file = '/Volumes/TEMP/KDACCT.TXT'
>>> f = open(file, 'r')
>>> s1 = f.read().rstrip('\r\n')
>>> s1
'01:25 \xe2\x87\x92 12/24/2019 \xe2\x87\x8901:31 DISK F \xe2\x99\xa3 '
>>> c2h(s1)
'30313a323520e287922031322f32342f3230313920e2878930313a3331204449534b204620e299a320'
```

I get what I was expecting, however if I take the same file in Windows or Linux I get a ValueError.

Here is the Windows interaction:
Windows: Python 3.6.8

```
>>> file = 'c:\\temp\\kdacct.txt'
>>> f = open(file, 'r')
>>> s1 = f.read().rstrip('\r\n')
>>> s1
'ï»¿01:25 â‡’ 12/24/2019 â‡‰01:31 DISK F â™£ '
>>> c2h(s1)
I get ValueError: ord value of char @ position:10 is > 255
```

Notice that Windows stores the BOM.

And here is the Linux interaction:
Linux: Python 3.6.8

```
>>> file = '/media/sf_Linux_SHR/KDACCT.TXT'
>>> f = open(file, 'r')
>>> s1 = f.read().rstrip('\r\n')
>>> s1
'01:25 ⇒ 12/24/2019 ⇉01:31 DISK F ♣ '
>>> c2h(s1)
I get ValueError: ord value of char @ position: 6 is > 255
```

My question is how do I get the same results in Windows/Linux as I did on the Mac.
I think it has to do with encoding, I just can't figure out what needs to happen.

Comment: You should be reading the file in binary mode (`'rb'`) if you want to treat it as bytes.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues at play here

1. You are reading a binary file as an ascii file. You should use `rb` instead of `r` as argument for `open()`
2. You are mixing Python 2 and Python 3 which behave a bit different in this case.

Here's a version that should work for both:

```py
from __future__ import print_function


with open('/Volumes/TEMP/KDACCT.TXT', 'rb') as fh:
    characters = bytearray(fh.read())
    for character in characters:
        print('%02x' % character, end='')
```